# Array de Objetos y Constructor en java

Tags: java, array, constructor

Este ejemplo está en una ficha de Java con la que estoy estudiando, al lado de los constructores plantee mis dudas.

*Multiplicar por `k` , los elementos de un arreglo.*

A modo de no sobrecargar el metodo main , se crea una clase llamada arreglo:

#### clase Arreglo

```
public class Arreglo
{
        private int v[];
    
    public Arreglo() //En este Constructor se crea el objeto arreglo y define su dimension /(5 elementos ) 
    {
        v = new int[5];
    }
    
    public Arreglo(int n) //en el segundo Constructor si el valor que le enviamos es menor = 0  ,  el Constructor lo redimensiona
    {
        if (n <= 0) n = 5;
        v = new int[n];
    }
    
    public int length() . Este metodo es necesario aplicarlo? retorna la longitud ,pero por que crea un metodo?
    {
        return v.length;
    }
    
    public int getComponent(int i)  
    {
        return v[i];
    }
    
    public void setComponent(int x, int i) // este metodo es la dimension que va tomar mi atributo de clase ? 
    {
        v[i] = x;
    }
    
    public void multiplicar(int k)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
        {
            v[i] = v[i] * k;
        }
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        String r = "{ ";
        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
        {
            r = r + v[i];
            if (i != v.length - 1) 
            { 
                r = r + ", "; 
            }
        }
        r = r + " }";
        return r;
    }
    
}
```

---

#### clase Principal

```
public class Principal
{
    private static Arreglo a;
    
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int n, k;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("¿Cuántos elementos?: ");
            n = Consola.readInt();
        }
        while(n<=0);
            a = new Arreglo(n);
            cargar();
            System.out.print("Valor k: ");
            k = Consola.readInt();
            a.multiplicar(k);
            System.out.println("Así quedó: " + a.toString());
    }
    public static void cargar()
    {
        int i;
        System.out.println("Cargue los números del arreglo: ");
        for (i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
        {
            int x;
            System.out.print("a[" + i + "]: ");
            x = Consola.readInt();
            a.setComponent(x, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Los arrays tienen su propio método `length`, por lo que no veo qué necesidad haya de declarar también en tu clase un método `length`. En cuanto a `setComponent` eso es lo que hace, dar a `v` la dimensión de `i` Aunque no le encuentro mucho sentido porque en el constructor el objeto es inicializado con otro tamaño. No sé exactamente cuál es la finalidad de tu clase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!Buenas!

Debes de acostumbrar a que un constructor no lleve condicionales ni demasiado contenido ( a no ser que sea estrictamente necesario). El constructor se utiliza para **iniciar**.

En esta parte de tu codigo:

```
    public Arreglo(int n) //en el segundo Constructor si el valor que le enviamos es menor = 0  ,  el Constructor lo redimensiona
{
    if (n <= 0) n = 5;
    v = new int[n];
}
```

Deberías de iniciarlo de esta forma:

```
    public Arreglo(int n) {

    v = new int[n];
}
```

Ya que en tu clase **main** estas pidiendo al usuario que introduzca la cantidad de elementos que llevara el **array**. Ahí es donde debes de "jugar" con los condicionales y asignarle un valor u otro...

Me refiero a esta parte de tu código:

```
do
    {
        System.out.print("¿Cuántos elementos?: ");
        n = Consola.readInt();
    }
    while(n<=0);
        a = new Arreglo(n);
```

Después otro punto a comentar, es este método que preguntas:

```
    public void setComponent(int x, int i) // este metodo es la dimension que va tomar mi atributo de clase ? 
{
    v[i] = x;
}
```

Pues realmente no se que quieres conseguir con el, pero a simple vista estas asignando un numero a una posición, donde ambos los pides en los parámetros del método.

Y este metodo:

```
    public int length() . Este metodo es necesario aplicarlo? retorna la longitud ,pero por que crea un metodo?
{
    return v.length;
}
```

Puedes quitarlo, ya que los array tienen su propio `.length`. Y puedes utilizarlo desde el **main**.

Espero que con esto te ayude a ver un poco mejor tu código.  Un saludo.